# Ninject context extraction from factory parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scope, ninject

I have an object that defines a scope:

```
Bind<ISomething>().To<Something>().DefinesNamedScope(SomethingScope);
```

I also have a auto-generated factory that creates IAnotherThing:

```
public interface IAnotherThingFactory
{
   IAnotherThing CreateAnotherThing(ISomething x);
}
```

And bind it:

```
Bind<IAnotherThingFactory>().ToFactory();
```

I would like to create the IAnotherThing in the context of ISomething, so I can e.g. have a ISharedPrivateDependency that both get the same instance of. However, Something must not be aware of IAnotherThing. That means that, ideally, there should be a way to extract the context from the ISomething parameter, and use it to set the context for IAnotherThing.

What binding do I have to define or code to write in order to get this behavior?

I do not want to expose the kernel directly, only the factory.

Edit after comments:

- Putting the Factory for AnotherThing into ISomething solves the context problem, but exposes ISomething to IAnotherThing. A requirement for an answer is stated above: ISomething must not be aware of IAnotherThing. So that's a no-go.
- The same goes for exposing Ninject-internals in the ISomething interface.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "context"? Are you asking how to have `IAnotherThing` be available inside of `ISomething` without `ISomething` knowing about `IAnotherThing`? ....

Comment: Context in the sense of the Ninject Context Preservation Extension.

Comment: Do you explicitly need to use the `ToFactory()` or is it viable to create a factory/provider of your own?

Comment: I would prefer ToFactory(), but it's not a requirement.

Comment: Ninject has no feature to retrieve the context of a previously instanciated object. Thus your requirements cannot be fulfilled without modifying ninject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at ninject contextpreservation extension: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.contextpreservation/wiki

`ISomething` will need to provide the `IAnotherThingFactory` (p.Ex. as property) in order for the objects created by `IAnotherThingFactory` to use the same context as `ISomething`.

Hint: The scope of the factory can be relevant. If you define the factory `.InSingletonScope` it won't work, or rather, all objects created by the factory will have the same context as the object that first requested the factory.

In case you need it even more generic, what you can do is inject an `IResolutionRoot` into `ISomething` and provide it as property. Then someone can do `ISomething.ResolutionRoot.GetContextPresreving<IFoo>();` or even
`ISomething.ResolutionRoot.GetContextPresreving<IAnotherThingFactory>().CreateAnotherThing();`

If you don't want to reference ninject, what you can do is hide `IResolutionRoot` in a wrapper `IFactory`, like:

```
internal class Factory : IFactory {

    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public Factory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot) {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    T Create<T>() {
        return this.resolutionRoot.GetContextPreserving<T>();
    }
}
```

However i suggest that this can probably be solved by improving the design (in a larger scope). For us at least it was never necessary to do such a thing - even though we have the requirement of late creating objects in the same context as another object, while the creation is triggered from a different context.

Comment: Yes, this might be solved by putting the factory onto the ISomething. But I explicitly do not want to do that (that's why I wrote that ISomething must not know IAnotherThing). And if I make a resolutionroot public, I expose ninject, which I do not want to do either.

Comment: Then wrap`IResolutionRoot` behind another interface, like `IFactory.Create<T>()`.